# How to set an array containing data from firestore query result in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, web-development-server

I successfully get the Orders with order_id and orders_data from firestore database and show in console, but I am unable to set the state of orders variable, I'm noob here.
I tried the commented part but it doesn't work to setOrders. Please give any solution and do tell why my commented part isn't setting data.

Orders.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Orders.css';
import { db } from './firebase';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import { doc, query, getDocs, orderBy, collection, getDoc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import Order from './Order';

function Orders() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]); //Initial value will be empty array

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(user){
      async function fetchData() {
        // You can await here
        const ordersRef = collection(db,"users",user?.uid, "orders");
        const q = query(ordersRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
        
        //console.log("Got Orders>>",orders)
        //   setOrders(querySnapshot.forEach((doc =>({
        //     id: doc.id,
        //     data: doc.data()
        //   }))));
        //...
     }
      fetchData();
     }else{
       setOrders([]);
     }  
  }, []); //You have to have [] here. This makes it run only once. 

  return (
    <div className="orders">
        <h1>Your Orders</h1>
        <div className="orders__order">
          {orders?.map(order =>{
            <Order order={order}/>
          })}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Orders
```

Order.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import CheckoutProduct from './CheckoutProduct';
import './Order.css';
import moment from 'moment';

function Order({order}) {
  return (
    <div className="order">
        <h2>Order</h2>
        <p>{moment.unix(order.data.created).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mma")}</p>
        <p className="order__id">
            <small>{order.id}</small>
        </p>
        {order.data.basket?.map(item =>{
            <CheckoutProduct
            id = {item.id}
            title = {item.title}
            image = {item.image}
            price = {item.price}
            rating = {item.rating}
            />
        })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Order
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data() is a queurySnapshot Object and it does not have a map fucntion to use, so we have to do it like this.

```js
setOrders(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc =>({
    id: doc.id,
    data: doc.data()
})));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see.
You should use map function instead of foreach

```
setOrders(querySnapshot.map((doc =>({
    id: doc.id,
    data: doc.data()
}))));
```

Comment: Tried this, it gives an error as following > Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: querySnapshot.map is not a function
    at fetchData (Orders.js:24:1)

Comment: Could you send me console.log(querySnapshot) above setOrders function?

Comment: This is what it prints in console when i run my code above in question>>>>>>>>>>pi_3LmMyUAkzUGZaOjE1Y7RNSG2  =>  {basket: Array(4), created: 1664220498, amount: 449711}amount: 449711basket: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]created: 1664220498[[Prototype]]: Object
Orders.js:21>>>>>>>>>> pi_3LmJ0KAkzUGZaOjE1ltWM9ic  =>  {amount: 326118, created: 1664205236, basket: Array(7)}

Comment: When i do console.log(querySanpshot) above setOrders, it prints this>>>>>xh {_firestore: Na, _userDataWriter: cl, _snapshot: $u, metadata: Sh, query: Ea}
Orders.js:24 xh {_firestore: Na, _userDataWriter: cl, _snapshot: $u, metadata: Sh, query: Ea}

Comment: querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
this worked for you?

Comment: querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data()); })

This gives me the output as shown in my second comment.
I get the user_ID as pi_xyz...
and I get data in basket type object, that has array of items.

Comment: let arr = [];
querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
arr.push({
     id: doc.id,
     data: doc.data()
})});
setOrders(arr);

Comment: Brother Brother Brother.. I solved it. Basically I had to use it like this as data is a QuerySnapshot object and it does not have map function according to documentation. 
setOrders(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc =>({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data()
        })));
        console.log("Got Orders>>",orders)

Now i get the value in orders.

Comment: ok, good. all the best